# Unable to get correct result using trapezoid rule

Tags: matlab

My professor wants me to use matlab to take the trapezoidal rule to approximate the area under `v=-300*t.^2+2700*t` for `t=[0:dt:9]` and `dt=0.1`. I am not allowed to use the function `trapz`.

I tried using

```
v1=v(1:end-1)
v2=v(2:end)
x_total=1/2*range(t)*dt*sum(v1+v2)
```

but ended up with

```
x_total =

3.2801e+05
```

which is nowhere near the actual area of 36450

Moreover, I manually computed the trapezoidal rule for subinterval 10 and got 36085.5.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trapezoidal formula does not involve range(t). The step size dt already reflects the length of the interval. So, use

```
0.5*dt*sum(v(1:end-1) + v(2:end))
```

Answer (score 0):

The area under a curve, if I remember correctly is the Riemann sum of f(x) from x=a0 to x=a1, which is approximately equal to the the sum of the rectangle areas with a period of dt.  Sooo...

```
sum(v(:) .* dt)
```

this also comes out to the same answer as the other dude.

Sorry, I had a quick date, forty, and a smoke to have....

Oops, my bad.  If the answers were the same, then the following would zero.

```
sum(v(:) * dt) - 0.5*dt*sum(v(1:end-1) + v(2:end)) = 7.27596e-12
```

So, I compared the answers:
    Answer_A = 36450 - 0.5*dt*sum(v(1:end-1) + v(2:end));
    Answer_B = 36450 - sum(v(:) * dt);

```
% Answer_X defines the difference from the truth
% If Answer_A < Answer_B
%    "0.5*dt*sum(v(1:end-1) + v(2:end))" is closer to truth
% elseif Answer_A > Answer_B
%    "sum(v(:) * dt)" is closer to truth

Answer_A < Answer_B   resolves false
Answer_A > Answer_B   resolves true
```

I'd go with my answer, unless there is a problem where this is not true.  Maybe the above was unnecessary, considering the difference between the solutions came out to a positive number, when subtracting mine from the other.

```
sum(v(:) * dt
```

I'm interested in seeing your work, like a picture or something, to find where you may have gone wrong to get 36085.5

Also, here is the path to trapz.  I know you're not allowed to use it, but the file is clear text ascii dot m.  Then you can learn how matlab does it, and use the relevent portion for your needs.

```
${MATLAB_APP_PATH}/toolbox/matlab/datafun/trapz.m
```

questionable cheating is my game :)

Additionally, the function trapz() seems to come out exactly with the average  (Answer_A + Answer_B) / 2